# Is there an issue with this method of reversing a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

```
public static Node reverse(Node curr, Node ogHead) {
    // base case if we end up back at the head of the original list return
    // our new list
    if (curr == ogHead) {
        return ogHead;
    }

    // ogHead is initiall setup to be the tail of curr now the current node
    // of curr is added to ogHead
    ogHead.addNodeAfter(curr.getData());

    // set the curr node equal to the next node in the list
    curr = curr.getLink();
    // call the method again with the new current element and the updated
    // new list

    reverse(curr, ogHead);

    return ogHead;

}
```

I have since graduated but i am wondering if this is an acceptable way of reversing a linked list. I believe the feedback i originally got is that it worked but it could have been made easier to test. The curr parameter i pass the head of the list, and the parameter ogHead i pass the tail of the list using a getTail() method.

Comment: If this code works, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't leave this one alone. Here's a better implementation of the recurse method, where nodes are just moved around to accomplish the reversal:

```
public static Node reverse(Node curr, Node ogHead) {
    // base case if we end up back at the head of the original list return
    // our new list

    if (curr == ogHead) {
        return ogHead;
    }

    Node oldOgHead = ogHead.link; // Remember what is behind (the original) ogHead
    Node nextCurr = curr.link; // Remember curr's successor (which is the starting point for the next recursion)

    // Move/insert curr right after ogHead
    ogHead.link = curr; // Put curr after ogHead
    curr.link = oldOgHead; // Whatever was after ogHead, put it after curr

    curr = nextCurr; // Prepare for next recursion

    if (curr != null) {
        reverse(curr, ogHead);
    }

    return ogHead;
}
```

No waste of memory, just references being updated.

Answer (score 0):

The code might work. It is all a matter of how `addNodeAfter` is implemented. Maybe you can update the question by adding the implementation.

If it is like this, you get a list in reverse order given that you start traversing it at ogHead:

```
class Node {

    private Object data;
    private Node link;

    public Node(Object data, Node link) {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void addNodeAfter(Object data) {
        link = new Node(data, link);
    }

}
```

But only because new nodes are created as the linked list is traversed. The original linked list  will still be there. So if you started with the list 1->2->3->4 you will now have the list 1->2->3->4->3->2->1 which is probably not what you wanted. I don't see any other way to implement `addNodeAfter` when it is only given the data part of a `Node`.

Comment: Yes that is how my addNodeAfter is implemented. And I see what you are saying. Reason i never considered this is when printing my list I always started with the node in which I considered the head. So doing this Node newList = Node.reverse(oldHead,oldHead.getTail()) then System.out.println(newList) where I have overridden the toString to print list from current position until end. So my list would still contain 1 2 3 4 I just have never saw them because I never tried reprinting from the original head of the list

Comment: Ok, then your implementation gives you the expected outcome but with an unnecessary waste of memory. So it works but it is far from optimal.